# How i use this style in react... " class[attribute] " [Edited v.2]

Tags: css, reactjs

I wanna custom my element if he has an attribute...

In pure css i just would use:

```
<div class='something' data-test='4'></div>
...
.something[data-test] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

but in react i'm failing to convert this code...

```
<div dataTest={0} className={classes.something} >
    Lorem Ipsum
</div>
...
    something: {
      "&[dataTest]": {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      }
    }
```

so, where i'm wrong ?

PS: i tried too:

```
"& [data-test]": {
"&.[data-test]": {
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `className`, not `class`. Then in CSS:

```css
.something[data-test="4"]  {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can access [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) in react. here is a quick [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-cartwright-m3nvm)

```
return (
    < >
      <div className="test" data-id="4">
        <h1>Hello dear world</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

**styles.css**

```
.test {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div::before {
  content: attr(data-id);
}
```